# AlphaNumeric Regex that could be all Letters or Numbers only or both

Tags: regex

Can someone please suggest a regex for a string that is AlphaNumeric. It should allow the format to be a mix of both numbers & letters, as well as all letters or all numbers.

So for example, these are all formats are all valid  - `C123456` or `123456` or `ABCDE`

Comment: Have you tried anything? What regex engine is it?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`  this is enough

Comment: Yeah sorry i had a bug in a test that i'd written, so i was already on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer - ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ , i had an issue in my tests, so it was wasn't working.